# how to populate an object using ado.net with sqlparameter

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to populate my object (`oSiteCompany`) using method override, when I use `SelectQueryProc()` with 20 parameters it is working but when I pass only 1 parameter(`COMPANY_ID`) `SqlException` was caught indicating that Procedure or function `pSiteCompany_GetSiteCompanySingleByCompanyID` expects parameter `@CompanyID`, which was not supplied.

Can anyone suggest what causes the error? Thanks in advance!

```
public List<oSiteCompany> GetSiteCompanySingleByCompanyID(string companyID)
{
    List<oSiteCompany> newSiteCompany = new List<oSiteCompany>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[1];
    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@COMPANY_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    sqlParam[0].Value = companyID;

    CommonDAL commonDAL = new CommonDAL();
    dt = commonDAL.SelectQueryProc("pSiteCompany_GetSiteCompanySingleByCompanyID", sqlParam);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        newSiteCompany.Add(new oSiteCompany()
        {
            CompanyID = dr["COMPANY_ID"].ToString(),
            CompanyName = dr["COMPANY_NAME"].ToString(),
            Type = dr["TYPE"].ToString(),
            Description = dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString(),
            FormulaID = dr["FORMULA_ID"].ToString(),
            Address1 = dr["ADDRESS1"].ToString(),
            Address2 = dr["ADDRESS2"].ToString(),
            Address3 = dr["ADDRESS3"].ToString(),
            Address4 = dr["ADDRESS4"].ToString(),
            City = dr["CITY"].ToString(),
            State = dr["STATE"].ToString(),
            PostalCode = dr["POSTAL_CODE"].ToString(),
            CountryCode = dr["COUNTRY_CODE"].ToString(),
            Status = dr["STATUS"].ToString(),
            BillingReport = dr["BILL_REPORT"].ToString(),
            AccountCode = dr["ACCOUNT_CODE"].ToString(),
            OrderNumber = dr["ORDER_NUMBER"].ToString(),
            CostCenter = dr["COST_CENTER"].ToString(),
            ReferenceNumberSequence = dr["REF_NUM_SEQ"].ToString(),
            InvoiceRemarks = dr["REMARKS"].ToString()
        });
    }
    return newSiteCompany;
}

public DataTable SelectQueryProc(String _storedProc)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CommonEntity.ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_storedProc, sqlConnection))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.Fill(t);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        throw new SystemException(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return t;
}

public DataTable SelectQueryProc(String _storedProc, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CommonEntity.ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_storedProc, sqlConnection))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
                adapter.Fill(t);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        throw new SystemException(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: because a stored procedure needs to populate all the parameters you specified in it. so if you pass only it only means that there are more parameters that needs to be populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter name is wrong, it should not have underscore. Change

```
sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@COMPANY_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

to

```
sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Szymon.. i have accidentally mispelled my parameter in which my CompanyID in other sp is spelled as Company_ID.